# Gesture recognizer in Interface builder crashes my app

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, ios5, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to make a gesture recognizer in my app with Interface Builder.
I drag and drop my gesture on my view (it is a `UIView` which contains `UILabel`, `UIImage` and `UITextView`, all made in Interface Builder).

But when I compile and run, my app crashes and I get the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString setView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x80a5fd0'
```

I don't understand the reason.

Can someone help me?

Comment: which iOS you are using?? iOS 5??

Comment: Please show the code of the event fired on gesture touch

Comment: I'm using iOS 5, and I haven't any code for my gesture recognizer because I made it in Interface Builder so I just drag and dropped it on my view in IB.

Comment: cross check your IBOutlet.if your IBoutlet is not matched then also it causes the problem.Another case is check your ios simulator is running  as the ios5.0 or not.if possible post some of the code for better results from us.

Comment: I checked my IBOutlet and all appears to be good, my simulator is running iOS 5.0 so it's ok too.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?  Have this too.

Comment: No sorry, I made it with another method; programmatically

Comment: See the following question that handles the same topic: [Crash when using gesture recognizers in StoryBoard][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035826/crash-when-using-gesture-recognizers-in-storyboard