# Crash when using gesture recognizers in StoryBoard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, interface-builder, xcode-storyboard

**UPDATE**

This is an old question for an old version of Xcode. It turned out that the issue was a bug in Xcode which has been fixed.

**Original**

I have a storyboard generated from making a new tab iphone application (with ARC)

In one of my tabs, if I drag a gesture recognizer (any, but let's say Pan) onto a control, and then set the selector to an action, it just crashes as soon as I go to the tab.

There is nothing in the Console -- it appears to be happening while the storyboard is being loaded (viewDidLoad is never called).

1. I can't figure out how to get more information
2. On a different tab, this works fine.  Both tabs were generated automatically.

(it's possible I messed something up in the view, but I don't have a clue to figuring out what I did).

If I make gestures programmatically, they work fine, but it's nice to have it work in the storyboard, and I'm afraid that whatever is wrong will cause a crash some other way at some point.

**MORE INFO**

In the simulator I get

```
-[__NSCFString setView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d2db70
```

Again, need debugging techniques -- for example, is there a way to find out what object 0x6d2db70 is?

Which is exactly like this question (with no answer):

[Gesture recognizer in Interface builder crashes my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385191/gesture-recognizer-in-interface-builder-crashes-my-app)

**MORE INFO**

This is trivial to reproduce

1. New iPhone tabbed application, ARC and Storyboard on
2. Drag tap gesture onto second tab's view (works on first one)
3. Create an (IBAction)
4. Connect the gesture's selector connection to the action from #3
5. run, go to second tab

Crashes.  Same thing with my app, default tab works, other tabs don't

Comment: What kind of crash?  SIGABRT?  EXC_BAD_ACCESS?  What's the stack trace?

Comment: That's the thing -- console has nothing.  Stack trace is back at main in the release pool (so it feels like memory corruption).  Need ideas for getting more info.

Comment: I have done a LOT of iPhone debugging, but new to 4.2, ARC, etc.  I would like ideas for new techniques (I know about zombies, debug malloc, etc -- but they don't seem appropriate).

Comment: Also, is there a connection that I need to make besides selector?  Does it connect to an IBAction with (id) sender?  I can't seem to find any good docs on this.

Comment: The action method signatures are documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  The method can take a sender parameter or not.

Comment: A stack trace pointing at main usually indicates that an exception was thrown.  Do you have an exception breakpoint set?

Comment: Besides setting the recognizer's target and action, it needs to be in at least one view's `gestureRecognizers` outlet collection.  You do that by dropping the recognizer on a view.  But it should be harmless if it's not in any `gestureRecognizers` collections.

Comment: Not near my computer right now -- will check all of this when I get to it -- thanks.  @rob, add an answer -- I think you've given me enough to solve -- I will edit it with the results.  Thanks.

Comment: It's trivial to reproduce -- I think it's a bug

Comment: Check that the target of the Gesture Recognizer is not deallocated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error message tells us that the program is sending the `setView:` message to an instance of `__NSCFString` (which is obviously the private implementation class of `NSString`).

Make sure you have tried running with zombies enabled.  A zombie can easily cause an unrecognized selector error.

If it's not a zombie, put a breakpoint on `-[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:]`.  When the breakpoint is hit, you may be able to figure out the problem just from the stack trace.  If not, you can print the `debugDescription` of the object (which is the same as the `description` for most classes).

On the simulator, you can ask the debugger to print the object's `debugDescription` like this:

```
(gdb) frame 0
#0  0x013bcbff in -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] ()
(gdb) po ((int*)$ebp)[2]
this is my test string
```

On the device, you do this:

```
(gdb) frame 0
#0  0x344bca22 in -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] ()
(gdb) po $r0
this is my test string
```

### Update

Based on your steps to reproduce, this is a bug in UIKit.  [File a bug report.](https://bugreport.apple.com/)  You can work around the bug by creating a strong outlet on `SecondViewController` and connecting it to the gesture recognizer.  <s>Make sure you set the outlet to nil in `viewDidUnload`.</s>

### Update

Do not ever set your outlet to nil -- part of the bug is that UIKit isn't retaining -- you need to keep your reference to make sure that the recognizers aren't released.

Comment: turning on zombies says the tap gesture is a zombie. -[UITapGestureRecognizer retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6b5ba80

Comment: I just noticed that UIImageView doesn't have a gestureRecognizers collection -- I have other UIImageView's where gestures work (also has the IB warning in the inspector).

Comment: The `gestureRecognizers` property is part of `UIView`, so `UIImageView` inherits it.  It is not tagged `IBOutletCollection`, so it only shows up in IB if you drop a recognizer on a view.

Comment: Do you have any `unsafe_unretained` outlets or variables?

Comment: Or any `assign` properties?  Under ARC, `assign` is the same as `unsafe_unretained`.

Comment: It's trivial to reproduce -- I think it's a bug (see updated question)

Comment: Everything is strong -- I have a trivial project that repros it.  No outlets or any variables

Comment: That's exactly what I did -- glad that you agree.  I am using ARC -- do I need to set the outlet to nil?

Comment: This was assigned Problem ID: 10771117 by Apple -- I will update this question if I hear that it was fixed

Comment: You need to set the outlet to nil in viewDidUnload.  Otherwise it won't get released on a memory warning.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot release in viewDidUnload -- when the memory warning comes, the app will crash because UIKit isn't keeping a retain -- you have to hold yours (you can see this by setting to nil in viewDidUpload and simulating a memory warning -- you will crash when you change tabs with a zombie warning)

Comment: Wow! I have been experiencing this issue as well, and it wasn't until I reviewed the Device Log in Organizer and found the doesNotRecognizeSelector was caused by the swipe that I managed to find this page. I have the same issue, and the fix above worked (just ctrl+drag the swipe gesture on to the header file of the backing view controller and make it a Strong Outlet - problem solved). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, when auto-creating the IBOutlet for the gesture recognizer by drag-n-dropping in the code, Xcode correctly created the property with a "strong" attribute, but it also added the "set to nil" in viewDidUnload. Removing the "set to nil" solved the issue for me.

Comment: That makes sense -- I ran into the same thing after I manually added in the IBOutlet in the standard way.