# Storyboard with Tab Bar controller as root crashes but only when custom controller is a tab that's not the first tab

Tags: ios, crash, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard, uigesturerecognizer

Situation:

- Custom controller that works fine under all circumstances... except in 1 case
- A storyboard with a tab bar controller as root
- Everything in the storyboard except the custom controller is pure prototyped in IB. Other than my custom controller, there is no code, just things dragged onto the story board. (I'm in the UI prototyping phase.)
- When I make the custom controller the first tab in the tab bar controller, it works fine.
- When connect the custom controller anywhere else in the storyboard, eg. as a modal controller for some other tab or as a controller in a navigation chain, it works fine too.

  - When I make the custom controller a tab in the tab bar controller that's NOT the first tab, it crashes.

The debugger says nothing more than 'BAD ACCESS'. The stack track shows nothing more than a crash in objc_msgSend and then UIApplicationMain. No useful debug information printed out.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Do you have a breakpoint defined to stop on the throw of Objective-C exceptions?  (It's a Breakpoint navigator option.)

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the storyboard layout along with the code for that custom class.  Also make sure to check that all of the VC's you have dragged onto the storyboard don't have any outlets, actions or any custom parent classes defined.

Comment: @PhillipMills: Phillip, enabling breakpoings in ObjC exceptions doesn't make a different. Thanks for the tip, though!

Comment: This turns out to be a dup of the following issue: [Crash when using gesture recognizers in StoryBoard][1].

Tom

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035826/crash-when-using-gesture-recognizers-in-storyboard